# Proper Unit testing with large projects

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel-5

I'm writing unit tests for a large API using Laravel, my concern is that due the complexity of the system, a single test requires a lot of previous conditions, such having a user, a session, an active area, etc. and since I'm using transactions (to avoid leaving test records in database), I need to create those previous conditions every test function ... and the code is growing pretty fast and tests are not unitary anymore (because I have to check every previous conditions before testing the actual target, ironically doing other unitary tests).

How do you handle such situation? Do you execute your tests in order and keep the state for futher tests? How do you handle mocking?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think what you described are unit tests. And running your tests with phpunit doesn't make them unit tests.

Comment: In the last days I have been reading a lot of testing and now I can see that there are different levels of tests, including unitary, acceptance and integration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following an approach like you outlined will quickly become unmaintainable.  One huge part of creating a large maintainable unit test suite, is to minimize cascading failures, by testing things in isolation.

If each test depends on other tests, then when the implementation of the dependency changes, there will be many unrelated test failures.  Testing things in isolation can help reduce this.  Creating isolated test, is a product of a clean architecture and [loosely coupled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling) components.  [Dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) generally plays a huge role in easily-testable designs.

One way to do this is to isolate dependencies, and only exercise your application logic.

Comment: I hope you don't mind me changing `maintainable` to `unmaintainable`. I'm about 95% certain it was a typo.

Comment: We are rebuilding that system (not from scratch thanks god) and I'm introducing TDD to the workflow so I'll do my best to keep things isolated.